# Can I force a subclass to implement a static parse-method?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a class hierarchy where all the implementing classes should have a range of static parse and parse-like methods. Can I somehow "force" them to implement these? I know I can't use `abstract static` since that's not allowed. Is there any other way to make sure these methods are implemented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't. You wouldn't be able to call them polymorphically anyway.

The best you can easily do is to put unit tests around this functionality.

I've previously suggested [static interfaces](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/29/lessons-learned-from-protocol-buffers-part-4-static-interfaces.aspx) available purely as a generic type constraint, which could be useful - but it's certainly not part of C# today, and I have no information that there are any plans to implement it :(